# Python float not callable

Tags: python

I'm doing an evolution experiment using python and pygame, however that is unimportant, it is one function that is not working and id like you to have a look at.

The error message I'm getting is float object is not callable. It says the problem is in line 205 which is calling the function from line 51.

I will post all my code most of which is irrelevant for fixing this problem. But i think its useful for you guys to have an idea of the code as a whole, and please dont hate me for lack of comments :P it will get there!!

thanks

Link to code: http://pastebin.com/BBm7Ehax

Comment: Please post the exact error message, including the full traceback.

Comment: `f = 1.234; f()` <-- not allowed

Comment: In future please attempt to isolate the problem as best you can and post code snippets in your question rather than linking to your entirety of your code. The last is especially important as all questions are archived so that people with the looking for answers to their problem can identity if they have the same problem as you do and then check the answers.

Answer (score 6):

Line 51:

```
def distance(self,listx,listy):
```

Line 55:

```
self.distance=(((self.x-self.tcentrex)**2) + ((self.y-self.tcentrey)**2))**0.5
```

You can't have `self.distance` be both a method and a variable and expect things to work properly.

When line 55 is executed (during the first time the `distance()` method is called) it overwrites the method (which was at `self.distance`, because it's the method `distance` being called on `self`) with a `float` value.

Comment: Well, you *can*, but it causes problems.

Comment: Thanks, sorry simple oversight on my part, i didnt see id called them both distance :) the code as a whole isn't working perfectly, but your help was much appreciated in getting it thre :)

Comment: You can mark this answer as having answered the question by clicking the green outline of a checkmark to the left, which will mark it as 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0):

In line 55, within the `distance` method, you assign a float value to `self.distance`. So after you call `distance` once, the attribute `distance` on that object refers to a float, which is not callable.